# How to post an Image file to a specific folder using ASP.NET WEB 2 Api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I can use `GET` and `DELETE`, but i'am struggeling with `POST`. I wanna post to a specific folder in the UWP app. Iam using image name is ID. I have this code for GET and DELETE.

```
//[Route("api/Image/{Name}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string name)
    {
        string file =$"C:\\Users\\bjornma\\source\\repos\\HuntHelper_v3\\Images\\{name}";
        var ext = new FileInfo(file).Extension;
        ext = ext.Substring(1);
        var img = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        var ms = new MemoryStream(img);

        var respons = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StreamContent(ms)
        };

        respons.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue($"image/{ext}");
        return respons;
    }

    public void Delete(string name)
    {
        string file = $"C:\\Users\\bjornma\\source\\repos\\HuntHelper_v3\\Images\\{name}";
        File.Delete(file);


    }
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Be clear and concise.

Comment: There is **no way** to control where any app/your website is storing the result you deliver from/content you post to your website. It is totally under control from the calling app/receiving website itself

Comment: Directly using an incoming value (i.e. name) in a file path on the server is a bad idea and at best could give you an error if the path doesn't exist and at worst is a potential security issue.

Comment: Can you post the image localy to my disk using the controller ?